# Pop to root SplitViewController in TabBarController - iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

TableViewController Context:
Here's my app:

```
Tab 1: NavigationController -> ViewController

Tab 2: SplitViewController -> NavigationController -> Master : TableViewController  ->TableViewController

                           -> NavigationController -> Detail : TableViewController  -> TableViewController


Tab 3: NavigationController -> ViewController (I'm Here)
```

How do I pop to the root of each tab from a method in the tab 3 (basically a logout button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to accomplish what I was trying to do, here's the code for others looking for the answer :

```
- (void) logout{
for(UIViewController *viewController in tabBarController.viewControllers)
{
    if([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
        [(UINavigationController*)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
    else if([viewController isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]]){

        UISplitViewController *splitView = (UISplitViewController *)viewController;
        for (UIViewController *navControllerInSplit in splitView.viewControllers) {
            if([navControllerInSplit isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
                  [(UINavigationController*)navControllerInSplit popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

// Based on UIviewController tag you can pop to navigate

// try this..

```
MyClass *obj = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

Comment: this would only be for the navigation controllers, it's the SplitViewControllers that I need to pop.
(on a side note, this didn't work for me on my normal views contained in a navigationContorller too)

Answer (score 0):

Add following code for pop to rootview for `UINavigationController` where `UITabbarController`

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([self.tabBarController.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        [(UINavigationController*)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    }

}
```

Reference: [View Controller Catalog for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313)

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create.

In other words, you must always install the view from a `UISplitViewController` object as the *root view* of your application’s window.

> The panes of your split view interface may then contain navigation
>   controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view controller
>   you need to implement your interface.

Split view controllers cannot be presented modally.

So, what you are attempting is incorrect, and in fact your app may get rejected by Apple.

Comment: sorry that's my fault, I misrepresented the diagram, I've updated my question.

Comment: rootview means . No tabbar it UISplitViewController must be the rootview

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you're allowed to have a splitview in a tabbarcontroller so long as the tabbarcontroller is the root